# Strange jumping behaviour with Bootstrap progress bar

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, progress-bar

I'm incrementing a bootstrap progress bar using javascript (See below). Every time the progress bar starts, it seems to jump to above the starting value, and then falls back down and correctly animates.

Perhaps the problem stems from the fact that the progress bar is hidden at first, but I've stepped through the code and it all looks fine.

Does anybody know how to get a smooth increment in the bootstrap progress bar?

Incrementing Javascript:

```
$(".click").click(function() {
  $(".progress").removeClass('hidden');
  var prog_bar = $(".progress-bar");
  var val = 0;
      (function myLoop (i) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            val += 1;
            prog_bar.attr('aria-valuenow', val);
            prog_bar.css('width', val + '%');
            if (--i) myLoop(i);
        }, 500)
    })(100);
});
```

See the JSFiddle for an example:

[**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/emMfS/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the css you're importing is setting a min-width of 30px on the rule:

```
.progress-bar[aria-valuenow="0"]
```

Easiest fix is to just override it in your html, or you could override it with pure css if you don't like inline css.  Just use the rule I specified above.

[Working jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/emMfS/1/)

```
  <div class="progress-bar" role='progressbar' aria-valuemax="100"
 style="width: 0px;min-width:0px;" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuenow="0">
```

Comment: Note that the min-width CSS in question is being removed in Bootstrap v3.2.1.

Comment: Great, setting the min width in the html worked. For some reason, it didn't work in the CSS. From cvrebert's comment, I'm assuming that this is a bug in Bootstrap? Still, your fix is what's needed - thanks

Comment: I guess I should have said in my comment - I tried `!important` and of course my CSS is after Bootstrap's.  Never mind though, in the HTML worked :)